# Acomodo de arreglos en Js

Tags: javascript

Tengo algo como  esto:

```
var ArrdeArr = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]]
var estado   = [estado1,estado2,estado3]
```

Y los  datos en los arreglos representan a un estado
por ejemplo **estado1** tienes los siguientes datos **1,5,9** y  así con cada estado.

Como puedo acomodarlo que quede de esta manera:

```
[estado1,[1,5,9]];
[estado2,[2,6,5]];
[estado3,[3,3,1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Básicamente creas otro arreglo vacio, haces un ciclo **for** donde le dices que "**i**" es igual a 0 y que a su vez "**i**" debe ser menor a la **longitud** de tu primer arreglo (3) y realizas un `push()` a el arreglo extra que creaste. Al utilizar `estado[i]` y `ArrdeArr[i]` la variable **i** se ira incrementando de 0 a 2 por lo que tomara los valores que estén en dichas posiciones, esto debido a que los arreglos comienzan desde 0.

```js
var ArrdeArr =[[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]];
var estado =['estado1','estado2','estado3'];
var arreglo = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ArrdeArr.length; i++) {
    arreglo.push(estado[i], [ArrdeArr[i]])
}

console.log(arreglo);
```

Con eso ya quedaría como lo quieres:

```
[estado1,[1,5,9]];
[estado2,[2,6,5]];
[estado3,[3,3,1]];
```

Comment: Una explicación de tu solución no estaría de más

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por la observación no note que lo había dejado muy a secas.

Comment: @Eduardo Javier Maldonado Lo estaba probando  y no  sale como  debería de salir :c  
También la ejecución de tu  ejemplo no da el resultado  espeerando

Comment: Pues entonces se más especifico porque el ejemplo que yo te puse @AlonsoSánchez es exactamente la que tu pusiste que esperabas.

Comment: A ver. Lo que tu ejemplo  está haciendo es diferente a lo que yo  espero:
Lo que tu  ejemplo  lo que hace es lo siguiente: 
Cuando i vale 0:
arreglo = [estado1,[1,2,3]]
¿Por qué? Porque el  for solo itinera en el contenido, no en los valores, y guarda el  arreglo que esta en la posición 0

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar 2 ciclos. El primero para crear la posición 0 de la nueva matriz y el segundo para crear la posición 1 y esta posición con los elementos en el orden que deseas

```
 var ArrdeArr =[[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]];
 var estado =['estado1','estado2','estado3'];
 var arreglo = [];

  for (var i in estado) {
  arreglo.push(estado[i])
   for (var j in estado) {
arreglo.push([ArrdeArr[j][i]])
 }
 }
```

Comment: Geniial!   Podrías explicarme un poco el for in, por favor?